# WebPack Dev Server doesn't start on Node.js 7.x

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm using `webpack@2.1.0-beta.27` and `webpack-dev-server@2.1.0-beta.11` last version packages. `webpack` works fine and it generates artifacts correctly.

After that, I would need to know to deal with an issue I've not been able to handle with `webpack-dev-server`.

I'm using three configuration files:

- [webpack.common.js](https://gist.github.com/jeusdi/134e19006a6f8da06bf4123c35d8a8a7)
- [webpack.dev.js](https://gist.github.com/jeusdi/365e8cc433ef629d6246776dce0e3092)
- [webpack.prod.js](https://gist.github.com/jeusdi/919e6228b753cbe67f72edfd613a8c99)

The error message `webpack-dev-server` is dumping me:

```
#webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --co
ntent-base src/
Project is running at http://localhost:3000/
webpack output is served from /
Content not from webpack is served from D:\projects\living\user-platform\project\src
404s will fallback to /
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: This socket is closed
    at WriteStream.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:683:19)
    at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:734:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:334:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:320:5)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:247:11)
    at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:661:40)
    at Console.warn (console.js:51:16)
    at printErrorAndExit (D:\projects\living\user-platform\project\node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js
:406:11)
    at process.emit (D:\projects\living\user-platform\project\node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:419:
16)
    at process._fatalException (bootstrap_node.js:292:26)
[default] Checking started in a separate process...
```

I don't know why it crashes and what does the message mean?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exact the same issue.

I solved this by downgrading Node.js to LTS 6.9.1.

With Node.js 7.2.0 I got the same error like above. Upgrading to 7.2.1 might  [solve the problem](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/9542#issuecomment-267046589) as well.

After some trial and error this issue in the angular cli repo pointed me in the right direction:
[ng serve error 'This socket is closed' #3102](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3102)

I hope this will help you fixing your problems temporarily.
Kirsten

Comment: Thanks a lot @KirKone . I've posed the question on [this issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/701) on webpack-dev-server project. They suggested me I remove `source-map-support`. However, I've no idea how to "delete" it. Have you any other ideas?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know you were running Node.js v7 when you posted that issue Jordi. There are indeed multiple issues with Node.js v7. Unfortunately those issues are with packages webpack-dev-server uses, not WDS itself.

Comment: @Jordi I think they wanted you to remove all references to it in your webpack.config.js. I did so but this did not fix the Problem for me.